# Is the official ISO image build script public / documented?

Tags: raspbian, image, script

We all know the [Raspbian Jessie Lite (Minimal image based on Debian Jessie)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) official ISO image from [www.raspberrypi.org](http://www.raspberrypi.org).

**Is the creation build script of this ISO image public / documented ?**
(i.e. all the steps that allow to *build* this image).

---

Context: For the project [SamplerBox](http://www.samplerbox.org) I started, it's important to be able to make images often, and having the script for the official image would be useful.

Here is a self-made image creation script (with the help of other people) : https://gist.github.com/josephernest/d0fd00ac5cf1c66b0cc1cf73fef6c85d.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by someone in freenode's #raspberrypi IRC channel, the build script is public:

https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen